# Openssl, Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: int BN_set_word(bignum_st *, ?) '

Tags: c++, c, openssl, bignum

I am using OpenSSL for a cuda project.

I just imported all the project from win to linux (Eclipse)

I solved all the dependencies except this annoying error:

> Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: int BN_set_word(bignum_st *, ?) '

for this line:

```
BN_set_word(two, 2);
```

and the function itself says in the bn.h

```
int BN_set_word(BIGNUM *a, BN_ULONG w);
```

Where BN_ULONG is defined as:

```
#define BN_ULONG    unsigned long
```

Neither it works if I do something like

```
unsigned long q = 2;
BN_set_word(two, q);
```

Because it returns

> Invalid arguments '
>   Candidates are:
>   int BN_set_word(bignum_st *, ?)
>   '

or

```
BN_ULONG q = 2;
BN_set_word(two, q);
```

that gives

> Type 'BN_ULONG' could not be resolved

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you forgot to `#include <openssl/bn.h>`.

Comment: @Junbogram That line was present in the included header. However the problem is some unknow bad config coming from windows... I created a new Project and imported piece by piece and it worked. I will mark your suggestion as answer because is related to that in anycase, thank :)